# finding the sound_play package

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

where do i find the sound_play package? It does not seem to be at this link any longer: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/sound_drivers/trunk/sound_play

Any help would be appreciated as i need this urgently to install a phidget package !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11528/finding-the-sound_play-package/) by [Sun](https://answers.ros.org/users/1213/sun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sun,

Search in the wiki when looking for sources.

Ros wiki : sound_play (http://www.ros.org/wiki/sound_play)

=> hg https://kforge.ros.org/audiocommon/audio_common

Et voila !

Guido

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3